# How to pre-populate Username field with Django

Tags: python, django

I have a ReviewsForm created in forms.py and I have a 'name' model in models.py in my reviews app. I want the name field in this reviewsform to be prepopulated by the full_name from my Profiles app if that's at all possible. I have achieved this in my course project for the Checkout process in a convuluted way. I tried recreating that method and cleaning it up but it's just not working as expected.

Somethings to add - I have a Profile Model and this is the model where the saved name is actually pulled from. I have imported this model into my reviews model.

My add_review function in views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_review(request):
    """ Add a review to the reviews page """
    if not request.user:
        messages.error(request, 'Sorry, you must login to do that.')
        return redirect(reverse('reviews'))
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewsForm(request.POST, request.FILES,)
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user==request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully posted a review, waiting for approval.')
            return redirect(reverse('reviews'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Failed to add review. Please ensure the form is valid.')
    else:
        form = ReviewsForm(initial={'name': profile.default_full_name,})

    template = 'reviews/add_review.html'
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
```

My checkout app views.py (I've highlighted the section of importance in bold, I think):

```
def checkout(request):
    stripe_public_key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY
    stripe_secret_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

    if request.method == 'POST':
        cart = request.session.get('cart', {})

        form_data = {
            'full_name': request.POST['full_name'],
            'email': request.POST['email'],
            'phone_number': request.POST['phone_number'],
            'country': request.POST['country'],
            'postcode': request.POST['postcode'],
            'town_or_city': request.POST['town_or_city'],
            'street_address1': request.POST['street_address1'],
            'street_address2': request.POST['street_address2'],
            'county': request.POST['county'],
        }
        order_form = OrderForm(form_data)
        if order_form.is_valid():
            order = order_form.save()
            for item_id, item_data in cart.items():
                try:
                    product = Product.objects.get(id=item_id)
                    if isinstance(item_data, int):
                        order_line_item = OrderLineItem(
                            order=order,
                            product=product,
                            quantity=item_data,
                        )
                        order_line_item.save()
                except Product.DoesNotExist:
                    messages.error(request, (
                        "One of the products in your cart wasn't found in our database. "
                        "Please call us for assistance!")
                    )
                    order.delete()
                    return redirect(reverse('view_cart'))

            # Save the info to the user's profile if all is good
            request.session['save_info'] = 'save-info' in request.POST
            return redirect(reverse('checkout_success', args=[order.order_number]))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'There was an error with your form. \
                Please double check your information.')
    else:
        cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
        if not cart:
            messages.error(request, "There's nothing in your cart at the moment")
            return redirect(reverse('products'))

        current_cart = cart_contents(request)
        total = current_cart['grand_total']
        stripe_total = round(total * 100)
        stripe.api_key = stripe_secret_key
        intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount=stripe_total,
            currency=settings.STRIPE_CURRENCY,
        )

       ** # Attempt to prefill the form with any info the user maintains in their profile
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                order_form = OrderForm(initial={
                    'full_name': profile.default_full_name,
                    'email': profile.user.email,
                    'phone_number': profile.default_phone_number,
                    'country': profile.default_country,
                    'postcode': profile.default_postcode,
                    'town_or_city': profile.default_town_or_city,
                    'street_address1': profile.default_street_address1,
                    'street_address2': profile.default_street_address2,
                    'county': profile.default_county,
                })
            except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                order_form = OrderForm()
        else:
            order_form = OrderForm()
**
        if not stripe_public_key:
            messages.warning(request, 'Stripe public key is missing. \
                Did you forget to set it in your environment?')

        template = 'checkout/checkout.html'
        context = {
            'order_form': order_form,
            'stripe_public_key': stripe_public_key,
            'client_secret': intent.client_secret,
        }

        return render(request, template, context)
```

Reviews models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from profiles.models import UserProfile


class Reviews(models.Model):
    """Defines the review model"""
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Reviews"

    review_title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    review_text = models.TextField(null=True, max_length=500)
    review_rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[
        MinValueValidator(1),
        MaxValueValidator(5)],
        null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="reviews_images/", null=True, blank=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                                     null=True, blank=True, related_name='review_profile')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the full URL to the reviews route as a string"""
        return reverse("reviews")
```

Checkout models.py:

```
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.conf import settings

from django_countries.fields import CountryField

from products.models import Product
from profiles.models import UserProfile


class Order(models.Model):
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, editable=False)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                                     null=True, blank=True, related_name='orders')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='Country *', null=False, blank=False)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    town_or_city = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False)
    street_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False, blank=False)
    street_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    delivery_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    order_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    grand_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    original_cart = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, default='')
    stripe_pid = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=False, default='')

    def _generate_order_number(self):
        """
        Generate a random, unique order number using UUID
        """
        return uuid.uuid4().hex.upper()

    def update_total(self):
        """
        Update grand total each time a line item is added,
        accounting for delivery costs.
        """
        self.order_total = self.lineitems.aggregate(Sum('lineitem_total'))['lineitem_total__sum'] or 0
        if self.order_total < settings.FREE_DELIVERY_THRESHOLD:
            self.delivery_cost = self.order_total * settings.STANDARD_DELIVERY_PERCENTAGE / 100
        else:
            self.delivery_cost = 0
        self.grand_total = self.order_total + self.delivery_cost
        self.save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Override the original save method to set the order number
        if it hasn't been set already.
        """
        if not self.order_number:
            self.order_number = self._generate_order_number()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_number

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_number    

class OrderLineItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lineitems')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    lineitem_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Override the original save method to set the lineitem total
        and update the order total.
        """
        self.lineitem_total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'SKU {self.product.sku} on order {self.order.order_number}'
```

I have tried chopping and changing my code multiple ways to have the name field pre-populated from the full_name field in my profiles model (user can update their profile).

I also read the suggested material which shows this example code:

No name was populated.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = IssueProcessForm(
        request.POST,
        initial={
            'number': get_issue_number,
            'title': get_issue_title,
            'body': get_issue_body
        },
    )
```

I fit that into my code like so:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewsForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial={
            'name': profile.default_full_name,
        },)
```

forms.py (ReviewsForm)

```
from django import forms
from .models import Reviews
from .widgets import CustomClearableFileInput


class ReviewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Creates the reviews form """

    class Meta:
        model = Reviews
        fields = ("name", "review_title", "review_rating", "review_text", "image")
    
    image = forms.ImageField(
        label='Image', required=False, widget=CustomClearableFileInput
    )
```

Comment: Could you please also disclose the definition of `ReviewsForm`?

Comment: @Dmitry Hi, thanks for responding and apologies for the terrible formatting and issues explanation. I have updated my post with the ReviewsForm (forms.py) at the bottom of my post. If any other information is required. Let me know. I wanted to use the user_profile as a unique identifier to enable the user who posted a review to edit & delete. Reviews don't have unique URL's etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to specify the "initial" value the first time you instantiate the form...like this:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # DON'T specify initial here - you want the submitted values
        form = ReviewsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
             # [... snip... ]
    else:
        # here is where you want initial....just when you are showing
        # the form for the 1st time
        form = ReviewsForm(initial={'name': profile.default_full_name,})
```

Comment: Apologies, I never updated the profile for the testuser I just created. Your solution 100% fixed this and I now understand how initial is working. I've changed it to profile.user to populate the name field with the username from allauth. There are so many ways to do things!!!